# How do you set global variables that don't get re-evaluated between feature methods

Tags: spock, geb

I have this example script that looks like this:

```
@Stepwise
class RandomTest extends GebReportingSpec {


    @Shared
    Random random = new Random()
    def tag = random.nextInt(999)+1

    def setupSpec() {
        new File('/ProgramData/geb.properties').withInputStream {
            properties.load(it)
        }
    }

    def "Random Test"(){
        when:
        println("Random1: ${tag}")
        println("Random2: ${tag}")
        then:
        Thread.sleep(1000)
    }

    def "Random test2"(){
        when:
        println("Random3: ${tag}")
        then:
        Thread.sleep(1000)
    }
}
```

In this example, Random1, and Random 2 print the same number, but Random 3 prints a different number.

for example this is my output when I run the code:

```
Random1: 528
Random2: 528
Random3: 285
```

I assume that this is because the Shared variables are re-evaluated between feature methods. I have tried moving those variable declarations outside of the `@Shared` annotation, to no avail.

I want it so that the random tag variable is generated at the beginning of the spec, and I want it to retain its value, but I am not sure how I would set up the global variables to do this. would I need to instantiate the variables inside of the setupSpec?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Shared` variables are *not* re-evaluated between tests. The reason for your observation is that you output the not `@Shared` variable `tag`. `random.nextInt(999)+1` is evaluated before each test method.

If you put a `@Shared` on `tag` the value won't change.

Comment: Yes I actually figured this out yesterday too. I always thought that the @Shared annotation applied to all the variables underneath not just the following variable. TIL

Comment: @switch201 that's just like in Java. You need one annotation per variable or method.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like insantiating the varaible from inside the setup spec is what works:

```
@Shared
def tag
def setupSpec() {
    new File('/ProgramData/geb.properties').withInputStream {
        properties.load(it)
    }
    Random random = new Random()
    tag = random.nextInt(999)+1
}

def "Random Test"(){
    when:
    println("Random1: ${tag}")
    println("Random2: ${tag}")
    then:
    Thread.sleep(1000)
}

def "Random test2"(){
    when:
    println("Random3: ${tag}")
    then:
    Thread.sleep(1000)
}
```